# Texto no ProgressBar

Tags: android

Yenho um `ProgressBar` em minha `MainActivity` e gostaria de adicionar um texto assim "*Carregando...*". Porém não estou conseguindo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

**Abaixo segue o codigo da minha atividade Principal.**

```
package prosportacademia.prosportacademia;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//Faz a verificacao da conexao com a internet
//Fim da Verifica��o de conexao com a internet

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings ws= wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setSupportZoom(false);
        //news implementation
        ws.setSaveFormData(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://bbacpropaganda.com.br/websport/users");
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        //Barra de Progresso / Carregando
        final ProgressBar Pbar;
        Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress < 100 && Pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                    Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

                }
                Pbar.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

                }
            }
        });
        //Fim da Barra de Progresso / Carregando


        }

//Fecha a Aplicacao Quando pressionar o botao voltar
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
   //Fecha a Aplicacao Quando pressionar o botao voltar




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: pbar.setMessage("Carregando"); nao funciona?

Comment: Olá Geferson,
Infelizmente não funciona, possui alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: O progressbar aparece na tela, só você não consegue colocar nenhuma mensagem, ou ele nem chega a aparecer?

Comment: Ele aparece na tela,  somente o circulo girando , porém quero adicioanar um texto para ficar mais intuitivo. :D

Comment: Sim sim, estranho eu uso a propriedade setMessage mesmo pra colocar mensagem nele.

Comment: para eu utilizar o setMessage qual pacote devo importar? to achando que deve ser isso.
Como sou iniciante em Dev. Android ainda apanho muito rs.

Comment: Aah não, agora que percebi, você está usando o progressBar, realmente ele não tem essa propriedade(setMessage), eu uso o progressDialog, pera ai que já posto um exemplo pra você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente utilizar dessa forma:

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setMessage("Carregando");
progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progress.setIndeterminate(true);
progress.show();
```

Comment: Boa tarde amigo,
Obrigado, porém só ta dando problema  em 
" new ProgressDialog(ctx);  " o que seria esse ctx?

Comment: é uma instância de sua activity, se estiver dentro de uma activity, pode substituir por this que vai funcionar. ... new ProgressDialog( this );

Comment: Geferson, só pude responder hoje devido a uma viagem de urgência. O que me passou funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado cara :)

Comment: Disponha, que bom que funcionou :)